# Remote desktop user cannot login

Tags: remote-desktop

Im playing with active directory on windows server 2003.

I created domain user, added him to Remote Desktop Users group, but still he cannot login using rdp. He is getting message that his account need to be added to Remote Desktop Users group.

What's wrong? Administrator can login without problems.

Comment: Login to what?  To the domain controller/workstation/member-server?

Comment: to server, which is domain controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give rights to logon locally to the Domain Controller.  Here is the MS article on how to do that.  [Permit users to log on locally to a domain controller](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785165%28WS.10%29.aspx)

[image]

Comment: do i have to restart server after that change? if not, it did not help.

Comment: If you did it through Group Policy you will have to update your machine policy.